# IDEA - Import maven projects

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 (Community Edition). I've a maven project which references other modules and jars. In one of the modules I've created/overwritten a class which is also in one of the jars. When I import (or reimport) the maven project, on the page Module Settings -> Project Structure -> Dependencies in IDEA, I can see that modules are always listed after the jar dependencies.

[image: Dependencies]

With this ordering, the classloader uses the wrong class and I get a compilation error. I can fix this when I move the modules above the jar which includes the class, but as soon as the maven project get reimported the order is wrong again.

How can I enforce that the modules are always imported on top of the dependency list?

Comment: What do you mean *created/overwritten*. Same package name and everything?

Comment: yes, same package and classname

Comment: Is it a properties file that can't be configured? Because that's typically an unwieldy way to handle things, and you'd typically try to exclude the class explicitly in maven.

Comment: is there a way you can share/exemplify a similar pom.xml?

Comment: The module common-server is the first dependency between the <dependencies> tag in the pom file. So if IDEA parses the pom top down it should be on top, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency order in Project structure is the same as in pom file, and you should not change anything in Project Structure, there is even a warning about that.

Change the dependency order in your pom.xml file - it will be changed automatically in IDEA and Project Structure view after next reimport